# LATERAL JOINS Causing Performance Issues

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, lateral-join

This query is for a Tableau dashboard. The users want to see the active clients in a sector as well as the contacts at those firms and how the composition of the data changes from quarter to quarter. I created a base time subquery and basically layer in the fact data.

I use `LATERAL JOINS` to place the data into their respective quarters using timestamps of the historical changes. I tested the query on a subset of the data and it ran well. When opening to the whole data set, the query cost becomes huge. I've already done some optimization but nothing seems to get the cost to an acceptable level.

All the tables have adequate indexes. The final `WITH` subquery, HACPCQ , where I utilize `LATERAL JOINS` to layer in the contact data is the issue. The two join tables have 500k rows and 3.5mn rows respectively. I can't get this to complete.

DB engineers won't create a view or stored procedure because of the potential cost to the prod server. No true replication DB available right now.

SQL and query plan below. The only posts I've seen on performance improvement are for a prior Postgres version. How should I rewrite these `LATERL JOINS`?

```
-- Q creates a baseline of quarters to analyze the client and contact tables over time. Last full year plus current year.

WITH Q AS (
    SELECT Q_Start, ((Q_Start + INTERVAL '3 months') - INTERVAL '1 day') :: DATE Q_End, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Q_Start DESC) Q_Rank
    FROM (
        SELECT GENERATE_SERIES( DATE_TRUNC('year', CURRENT_DATE) - INTERVAL '1 year', DATE_TRUNC('quarter', CURRENT_DATE), INTERVAL '3 months') :: DATE Q_Start
        ) q1
    ),

-- HA gathers the historic client records within the timeframe of Q and filters to the last change per quarter.

HA AS (
    SELECT id CL_ID, history_id CL_Hist_ID, history_date CL_Hist_Date FROM (
        SELECT ha.id, history_id, history_date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ha.id, EXTRACT(year FROM history_date),
               EXTRACT(quarter FROM history_date) ORDER BY history_date DESC) AS Row_Rank
        FROM historicalclient ha
        WHERE EXTRACT(year FROM history_date) >= (EXTRACT(year FROM CURRENT_DATE) - 1)
        ) ha1
    WHERE Row_Rank = 1
    ),

-- Tag clients to relevant quarters 

HAQ AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM Q
    JOIN LATERAL (SELECT CL_ID, MAX(CL_Hist_ID) CL_Hist_ID, MAX(CL_Hist_Date) CL_Hist_Date FROM HA WHERE CL_Hist_Date :: DATE <= Q.Q_End GROUP BY CL_ID) HA
    ON TRUE
),

-- Same deal as HA but for contactposition.

HCP AS (
    SELECT CP_ID, client_id CP_CL_ID, contact_id CP_Cont_ID, history_id CP_Hist_ID, history_date CP_Hist_Date, current FROM (
        SELECT hcp.id CP_ID, client_id, Cont_ID, history_id, history_date, current,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY hcp.id, EXTRACT(year FROM history_date), EXTRACT(quarter FROM history_date) ORDER BY history_date DESC) AS Row_Rank
        FROM contactposition hcp
        WHERE historydate >= '10/1/2023'
        ) hcp1
    WHERE Row_Rank = 1
    AND current = TRUE
    ),

-- HC is HCP but for contacts

HC AS (
    SELECT id Cont_ID, history_id Con_Hist_ID, history_date Con_Hist_Date FROM (
        SELECT hc.id, history_id, history_date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY hc.id, EXTRACT(year FROM history_date), EXTRACT(quarter FROM history_date) ORDER BY history_date DESC) AS Row_Rank
        FROM historicalcontact hc
        LEFT JOIN contactposition cp
        ON hc.id = cp.Cont_ID
        WHERE EXTRACT(year FROM history_date) >= (EXTRACT(year FROM CURRENT_DATE) - 1)
        ) hc1
    WHERE Row_Rank = 1
),

-- Joining all of the base data sources together

HACPCQ AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT *
    FROM HAQ
    LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT CP_CL_ID, CP_ID, CP_Cont_ID, MAX(CP_Hist_ID) CP_Hist_ID, MAX(CP_Hist_Date) CP_Hist_Date FROM HCP WHERE CP_CL_ID = HAQ.CL_ID AND CP_Hist_Date :: DATE <= HAQ.Q_End GROUP BY CP_CL_ID, CP_ID, CP_Cont_ID) HCP
    ON TRUE
    LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT Cont_ID, MAX(Con_Hist_ID) Con_Hist_ID, MAX(Con_Hist_Date) Con_Hist_Date FROM HC WHERE Cont_ID = HCP.CP_Cont_ID AND Con_Hist_Date :: DATE <= HAQ.Q_End GROUP BY Cont_ID) HC
    ON TRUE
)


    SELECT *
    FROM HACPCQ a
```

Query Plan

Edit: Switched out the full `EXPLAIN` query plan for the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` query plan of one client. Freed up characters in my post - link below.

https://explain.depesz.com/s/Cor5

Edit 2: Trimmed down query to make it more readable. Still filtered to one client. New `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` query plan below.

https://explain.depesz.com/s/Wxde

Comment: could you please share the results from `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)` for this statement? That gives all the details, not just a plan. The DDL for all tables and indexes involved would be helpful as well. Everything in plain text please

Comment: `DB engineers won't create a view or stored procedure because of the potential cost to the prod server.` How would a hardcoded query in a view or function be more costly than your current query? I don't want to be a total jerk, but this is nonsense

Comment: Seeing `SELECT DISTINCT *` is a huge red flag indicating either a lack of understanding of the relationships between the data or insufficient effort to effectively constrain the results. Either way, it is likely that a lot of unnecessary work is being done to discard redundant rows. Lateral joins essentially result in a separate subquery for each row of the driving tables, which is most likely why performance seems acceptable for a small subset of the data, but not for the full dataset. Consider revising the query to minimize, or better yet, eliminate, the use of lateral joins.

Comment: Run ANALYZE on your tables to update statistics, that helps the PostgreSQL query planner make better decisions. Also, run VACUUM to clean up dead tuples, which can improve performance.

Comment: @FrankHeikens I can't get the query to complete on the full data set so I'll have to run ANALYZE on a subset of the data. I've also run out of characters in my post so I'll have to include the results as an image. Regarding not creating a view or stored procedure, I think they are just overworked and don't want to take on another project...

Comment: @TSCAmerica.com SO won't let me mention multiple people in a comment but see what I wrote for Frank

Comment: @JohnH What do you consider to be the best workaround for not using a lateral join? I feel like I would need to create 4 more subqueries to replace it.

Comment: Post the query plan on https://explain.depesz.com and leave the link to that plan over here

Comment: @FrankHeikens That's a fancy app you got there: https://explain.depesz.com/s/Cor5

This is EXPLAIN ANALYZE on a single client.

Comment: You'll have better odds of getting an answer if you reduce your monstrous query to a minimal example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I trimmed the query down and posted the new `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` query plan

Comment: `Execution Time: 1.604 ms`, what kind of performance are you looking for? 1.6 milliseconds is not that bad.

Comment: @FrankHeikens Little refresher as people have had me cut down the query to make it more readable: I cannot get this query to complete when I open it up to the full data set. Both `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` Query Plans are of just 1 client. The issue is with the `LATERAL JOINS` in the final `WITH` HACPCQ subquery. I am layering data into the quarters I create in the Q subquery then dragging them to the following quarters if there's no update. Do you know of an alternative that still brings data from a previous quarter to a new quarter without using `LATERAL JOINS`?

Comment: Lateral joins can sometimes be rewritten with `DISTINCT ON`. To get an execution plan that demonstrates the problem, you could use medium sized tables. I know it is difficult to come up with a good and simple example, but it is also difficult to tune a query from afar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. An [`interval`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-INTERVAL-INPUT) constant can have an equation in it. You can do `interval '1 month -1 day'`, without having to separately subtract `interval '1 day'` from `interval '1 month'`.
2. [SRF](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html)s like `generate_series()` don't need wrapping in subqueries to be selected from.
3. Default to `row_number()` rather than `rank()` if you're just numbering rows.
4. If you simply add [`WITH ORDINALITY AS g(val,row_num)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS) when taking rows from a **S**et-**R**eturning **F**unction, you get numbered values. That way you don't have to collect, sort and number them separately, at all, removing the need for either `rank()` or `row_number()`.
5. Adding to `timestamp(tz)` implies `interval` addend, saving you an explicit cast.

[Here's a separate demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/5dQQDIIP) for the five points above applied to the first CTE `Q`.

6. As [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77830002/lateral-joins-causing-performance-issues#comment137282485_77830002) by [@Laurenz Albe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6464308/laurenz-albe), most of your subqueries can be shortened to a [`distinct on`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT). It selects the top/sample record per group without having to aggregate, number, then filter everything out except the `Row_Rank = 1` that keeps appearing in your code.
7. In `HAQ`, the two `max()` could return values from different rows. It's possible in your data they happen to always come from the same row, but in the query there's nothing enforcing that. `Distinct on` does enforce that, while also performing and optimising better.
8. [`CROSS JOIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-JOIN) is equivalent to `JOIN ON TRUE`, which is the same as just a comma `,`: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/zxYn2PA5).
9. The last `JOIN`s don't seem to need to be `lateral` and you don't need those subqueries at all: they re-do operations you already did and they already expose columns to match on.
10. There are slight inconsistencies in your query: is it `history_date` or `historydate` in `contactposition`? Does the same table have `Cont_ID`/`cont_id` or `contact_id` column, or both?
11. Unless you double-quote your identifiers, they get [folded to lowercase](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS), so `Q_Start` is just `q_start`. Unless you create and refer to it as `"Q_Start"`.

Applying all of the above, you can slightly clean up your query and speed it up 50x. [Demo:](https://dbfiddle.uk/-zWn70AS)

```sql
WITH Q AS (
  SELECT  Q_Start::DATE, 
          (Q_Start + '3 months -1 day')::DATE Q_End, 
          Q_Rank
  FROM GENERATE_SERIES(DATE_TRUNC('quarter',CURRENT_DATE),
                       DATE_TRUNC('year',   CURRENT_DATE) -INTERVAL '1 year', 
                       INTERVAL '-3 months')WITH ORDINALITY g(Q_Start,Q_Rank)
  ),
HA AS (-- HA gathers the historic client records within the timeframe of Q 
     -- and filters to the last change per quarter.
  SELECT DISTINCT ON (ha.id, 
                      EXTRACT(year FROM history_date),
                      EXTRACT(quarter FROM history_date) )
         ha.id        AS CL_ID, 
         history_id   AS CL_Hist_ID, 
         history_date AS CL_Hist_Date
  FROM historicalclient ha
  WHERE EXTRACT(year FROM history_date)>=(EXTRACT(year FROM CURRENT_DATE) -1)
  ORDER BY ha.id, 
           EXTRACT(year FROM history_date),
           EXTRACT(quarter FROM history_date),
           history_date DESC
  ),
HAQ AS (-- Tag clients to relevant quarters 
  SELECT * FROM Q
  ,LATERAL(SELECT CL_ID, 
                  MAX(CL_Hist_ID) CL_Hist_ID, 
                  MAX(CL_Hist_Date) CL_Hist_Date 
           FROM HA 
           WHERE CL_Hist_Date::DATE <= Q.Q_End 
           GROUP BY CL_ID) HA
),
HCP AS (-- Same deal as HA but for contactposition.
  SELECT DISTINCT ON (hcp.id, 
                      EXTRACT(year FROM history_date), 
                      EXTRACT(quarter FROM history_date)) 
          hcp.id AS CP_ID, 
          client_id AS CP_CL_ID, 
          contact_id AS CP_Cont_ID, 
          history_id AS CP_Hist_ID, 
          history_date AS CP_Hist_Date, 
          current 
  FROM contactposition hcp
  WHERE history_date >= '10/1/2023'
  AND current IS TRUE
  ),
HC AS (-- HC is HCP but for contacts
  SELECT DISTINCT ON (hc.id, 
                  EXTRACT(year FROM history_date), 
                  EXTRACT(quarter FROM history_date)) 
     hc.id AS Cont_ID, 
     history_id AS Con_Hist_ID, 
     history_date AS Con_Hist_Date
  FROM historicalcontact hc
  LEFT JOIN contactposition cp
  ON hc.id = cp.contact_id
  WHERE EXTRACT(year FROM history_date)>=(EXTRACT(year FROM CURRENT_DATE) -1)
  ORDER BY hc.id, 
           EXTRACT(year FROM history_date), 
           EXTRACT(quarter FROM history_date),
           history_date DESC
)
-- Joining all of the base data sources together

    SELECT DISTINCT ON (HAQ.CL_ID, HAQ.Q_Start, HCP.CP_Cont_ID) *
    FROM HAQ, HCP, HC
    WHERE HCP.CP_CL_ID = HAQ.CL_ID
      AND HCP.CP_Hist_Date::DATE <= HAQ.Q_End
      AND HC.Cont_ID = HCP.CP_Cont_ID
      AND HC.Con_Hist_Date::DATE <= HAQ.Q_End
    ORDER BY HAQ.CL_ID, HAQ.Q_Start DESC, HCP.CP_Cont_ID;
```

Comment: I've done a bunch of testing and this looks like almost a triumph on the first try! I just changed the final section into a `SELECT DISTINCT ON (HAQ.CL_ID, HAQ.Q_Start, HCP.CP_Cont_ID)` and ended with `ORDER BY HAQ.CL_ID, HAQ.Q_Start DESC, HCP.CP_Cont_ID`. Not sure if you can edit your post after I accept the answer so I'll let you change it before I do that if you wish.

Comment: Also, regarding point 10, I just got sloppy masking field names so that's where the  inconsistency comes from. For point 11, from a coding perspective, I just like to use some uppercase characters to denote fields I rename for better visibility when I'm scrolling through the code, so no real intent on case sensitivity there..

Comment: I've added an edit - let me know if that's what you meant. I think answers remain editable after being accepted/upvoted/rewarded in general. No need to explain points 10&11 - what you described is usually the case, but I figured it's just worth a mention&reminder.

Comment: I ended up being able to make an edit to your post in the final section.